# SHA Encryption - Are Salts Really Needed?

Tags: php, jquery, sha256

I'm using Jquery SHA512.js to sent encrypt and send a username and password to the server.
At the server I'm doing the following to create my DB stored HASH:

$dbhash = = hash('sha256',(hash('sha512',$user) . hash('sha256',$extremesalt)));

This all works fine.

My Question is what value is the Salt?
At the point the Salt is applied to the password, the password is already on the server and not in transit across the Internet. Also the Salt is stored next to the password hash.

Therefore it appears someone would need to get my table with hash's and if they did they could also get the salt and the rest of my code and do what they wanted with my site in general.

I can see its good to apply a salt and I will do so but as it only occurs on the server and not from the browser to the server I question its value. Am I missing something?

One other question - is it possible to apply a salt from the browser to the server. I assume not or at least if you did it would be visible if one checked the source (eg: in my cause visible in jquery). Thus of no real value.

thx

Answer (score 4):

The point of the salt is to make it harder to see if 2 people's passwords are the same. One thing about SHA is that it's not easily reversible. Most attacks involve generating hashes for common passwords so for reasonably complicated passwords it becomes harder especially with salts (some people use usernames as salts, others use randomly generated numbers). Usually you want to do this on the server side code (I don't think it's safe to do on browser code). You should also never store the actual password on the server you only store the hash (and maybe the salt if you don't already know it)

Upon a second look I see that you're using 2 hashes one after the other 256 and then a 512. This is a bad idea, use one and stick with it. You waste time computing multiple hashes.

Comment: I +1 your answer for the first paragraph.  The 2nd paragraph might be wrong in the future.  See my comment to Marc B.

Comment: @Marc, Yeah I actually read that paper a couple of weeks back it's quite interesting. Although there are techniques for hashing the hash which although have that effect, make it easier to actually find the original string. I had another paper that showed this somewhere but I can't seem to find it now.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing hashes like that is rather pointless. Taking an sha512 hash and running it through sha256 necessarily cuts the keyspace in half, so all you've done is waste cpu time and double the odds of a collision. The odds will still be vanishingly small/microscopic, but it's still something to consider.

The salt is there as a butt-covering mechanism. If for some reason your database were to leak (e.g. a dump file got "lost"), it would be trivial to generate an sha256/512 rainbow table of common passwords and see if there's any hits on your table. The hash is there to make it far more expensive to generate a rainbow table. e.g. "password" is easy to hash and check for. "password#^$@#%#^Y#@#$@#^%$^Y%%$" is far less likely to be rainbowed.

Comment: Using a salt also protects you from recovering common passwords from hashes... take for example a [google search for the md5 hash of "hello"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592)

Comment: @Chris: that's due to a rainbow table. md5 itself is not broken in that you can retrieve the original string from a hash, but it's now fairly trivial to calculate/orchestrate collisions to find a string that DOES hash to the same value. A salt doesn't protect against collisions, especially orchestrated ones.

Comment: @MarcB -- Due to the message expansion functions of SHA-2, running SHA-2(512) output through SHA-2(256) could strengthen resistance to calculating collisions via linear approximations -- see Sanadhya and Sarkar for references and info.  The complexity, in terms of operations performed, of SHA-256 is similar to SHA-512 -- for example little-sigma-1 function has 3 rotations and a shift XORd together.  SHA-512 doesn't have, e.g., 6 rotations and 2 shifts, it just has rotations which are larger because the SHA-512 registers are larger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your app, but wouldn't you want to just send the username/pwd to the server using SSL and let the public key encryption of SSL take care of the encryption for you.  The server can then generate an appropriate hash to either store the hashed password or to compare to a previously stored hash for verification.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbhash = = hash('sha256',(hash('sha512',$user) . hash('sha256',$extremesalt)));
```

Should be (no need for double hashing)

```
$dbhash = = hash('sha512',$pass + $salt);
```

Where pass is the password and salt is something unique about the user (userid for example). If you opt for random value you need to store it with the hash.